# Is there a way to create a hyperlink (with customized text) in a Github Action pipeline script?

Tags: github, github-actions

Part of my Github action pipeline is to notify a Slack channel on successful deployment. Within that notification, a hyperlink to the Github PR is injected. The issue is the hyperlink shows the full text of the URL, and not a specified (shorter) name.

Instead of showing the full link like this:
https://github.com/CompanyABC/repo1/pull/8

...I want to show something like this: [My PR](https://github.com/CompanyABC/repo1/pull/8)

So it's the same link, but just given a custom name. Here is the relevant part of my Github action pipeline script:

```
- name: Slack Notification
  uses: rtCamp/action-slack-notify@v2
  env:
    SLACK_COLOR: ${{ job.status }} # or a specific color like 'good' or '#ff00ff'
    SLACK_MESSAGE: "GitHub build result: ${{ job.status }}\nPR Title: ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}\nPR link: ${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url || github.event.head_commit.url }}"
    SLACK_TITLE: Deployment successfully completed
    SLACK_USERNAME: ${{ github.actor }}
    SLACK_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.DEVOPS_NONPROD_RELEASES_SLACK_WEBHOOK }}
```

Notice what I have defined for the SLACK_MESSAGE attribute. Is there some way in the action script of combining this:

```
github.event.pull_request.title
```

...and this:

```
github.event.pull_request.html_url
```

...to yield me this:

[My PR](https://github.com/CompanyABC/repo1/pull/8)

...instead of this:

PR Title: MY PR, PR link: https://github.com/CompanyABC/repo1/pull/8

?

Kinda like how this would work in regular web development:

```
<a href="https://github.com/CompanyABC/repo1/pull/8">My PR</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Turns out Slack has their own markup for HTML links:

```
<http://someurl|like this>
```

Instead of Github's methodology:

```
[like this](http://someurl)
```